# sass algorithm for flexbox order

Tags: css, algorithm, for-loop, math, sass

Actually the solution looking to build sass `order` based on `$items` for https://codepen.io/athimannil/pen/ZXeNVv. Currently the display order not working properly for the big screen because of bad algorithm. I think the solution might be replacing `order: #{floor(($i - 1)/4)*2 - $i%2};` in proper way with help of `$items`

```
.my-div #{&} {
  @media screen and (min-width: $breakpoint-xs) {
    @for $i from 1 through $items*2 {
      &:nth-child(#{$i}) { order: #{floor(($i - 1)/4)*2 - $i%2}; }
    }
  }

  @media screen and (min-width: $breakpoint-md) {
    @for $i from 1 through $items*2 {
      &:nth-child(#{$i}) { order: #{floor(($i - 1)/8)*4 - $i%2}; }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: ?? hello, what is the question ?

Comment: @G-Cyr  something wrong with algorithm, in demo large screen not working properly

Comment: okay, you should describe this in the question ;) to make it obvious to users that could help.

Comment: @G-Cyr updated the question